# Hopfield neural network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

do you know any application beside pattern recog. worthe in order to implement Hopfield neural network model?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand, you should be more specific if you want an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recurrent neural networks (of which hopfield nets are a special type) are used for several tasks in sequence learning:

- Sequence Prediction (Map a history of stock values to the expected value in the next timestep)
- Sequence classification (Map each complete audio snippet to a speaker)
- Sequence labelling (Map an audio snippet to the sentence spoken)
- Non-markovian reinforcement learning (e.g. tasks that require deep memory as the T-Maze benchmark)

I am not sure what you mean by "pattern recognition" exactly, since it basically is a whole field into which each task for which neural networks can be used fits.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise about their use with non-markovian reinforcement learning? You say they're used for tasks that require deep memory, but wouldn't multi layer backprops network do the same? What makes those best for the job? Thanks

Comment: Typically, you present the observations of the k last timesteps to an MLP to map it to an action or a value. That is something you can call "k-markovian". However, "deep memory" refers to situations when the number of timesteps you have to look back is not necessarily bounded. In that case, you need recurrent network which can (at least theoretically) look back in time an infinite number of timesteps. 

You might want to check this paper: http://www.idsia.ch/~daan/papers/jof.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hopfield network for optimization problems as well.

Comment: Maybe you can give an example/reference.

Comment: For example Travelling Salesman Problem or Shortest Path [link] (http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/~mandziuk/PRACE/TSP_DM.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this repository --> [Hopfield Network](https://github.com/yogonza524/HopfieldNetwork)

There you have an example for test a pattern after train the Network off-line. 
This is the test

```
 @Test
 public void HopfieldTest(){
     double[] p1 = new double[]{1.0, -1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0};
     double[] p2 = new double[]{1.0, 1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0};
     double[] p3 = new double[]{1.0, 1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0};

     ArrayList<double[]> patterns = new ArrayList<>();
     patterns.add(p1);
     patterns.add(p2);

     Hopfield h = new Hopfield(9, new StepFunction());

     h.train(patterns); //train and load the Weight matrix

     double[] result = h.test(p3); //Test a pattern

     System.out.println("\nConnections of Network: " + h.connections() + "\n"); //show Neural connections
     System.out.println("Good recuperation capacity of samples: " + Hopfield.goodRecuperation(h.getWeights().length) + "\n");
     System.out.println("Perfect recuperation capacity of samples: " + Hopfield.perfectRacuperation(h.getWeights().length) + "\n");
     System.out.println("Energy: " + h.energy(result));

     System.out.println("Weight Matrix");
     Matrix.showMatrix(h.getWeights());
     System.out.println("\nPattern result of test");
     Matrix.showVector(result);

     h.showAuxVector();
 }
```

And after run the test you can see

```
Running HopfieldTest

Connections of Network: 72

Good recuperation capacity of samples: 1

Perfect recuperation capacity of samples: 1

Energy: -32.0

Weight Matrix
 0.0        0.0     2.0    -2.0      2.0       -2.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
 0.0        0.0     0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0      -2.0       2.0    -2.0
 2.0        0.0     0.0    -2.0      2.0       -2.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
-2.0        0.0    -2.0     0.0     -2.0        2.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
 2.0        0.0     2.0    -2.0      0.0       -2.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
-2.0        0.0    -2.0     2.0     -2.0        0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0
 0.0       -2.0     0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0       0.0      -2.0     2.0
 0.0        2.0     0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0      -2.0       0.0    -2.0
 0.0       -2.0     0.0     0.0      0.0        0.0       2.0      -2.0     0.0

Pattern result of test 

 1.0        1.0     1.0     -1.0     1.0       -1.0      -1.0       1.0     -1.0
-------------------------
The auxiliar vector is empty
```

I hope this can help you